# Close share options on other articles when share is clicked

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking to add social sharing on a list of articles with AngularJS.
I've implemented toggling for pressing the share button, but if I click the share button on a different article, I want the options on this one to be closed.

Right now every single share option that appears when I click `.share-article` will stay open (effectively allowing clutter on the page). I only want the active one open.

```
<span class="article-title">
  <a href="{{article.url}}">{{article.title}}</a>
</span>
<div class="click-items">
  <a ng-click="articles.removeArticle($index)" class="delete-article clickable" title="Remove article">
    <span>&#10006;</span>
  </a>
  <a ng-click="socialShare = !socialShare" class="share-article clickable">
    <span class="plus-sign" title="Share">&#10006;</span>
    <div social-share ng-show="socialShare" class="social-share arrow-down">
      <div ng-click="socialShare = !socialShare" class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_16x16_style" 
      addthis:title="{{article.title}}" addthis:description="{{article.extract}}" addthis:url="{{article.url}}">
        <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone_share"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_reddit"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_hackernews"></a>
        <script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-529b989f77fb3475"></script>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

How can that be accomplished?

Comment: jsbin.com demo please?

Comment: @m59 Sorry I've never used JSFiddle for Angular before, how do I import the modules? I'm getting `No module: ngAnimate`

Comment: I don't prefer jsfiddle (why I recommended jsbin). For jsbin, include the scripts like you normally would. For jsfiddle, use the external resources tab on the left.

Comment: By the way, it is really a good idea to strip out all of the extra code and just post what is relevant to your issue. I see a ton of markup and classes etc that have nothing to do with your actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it happen you need to track the state of each of the share button set. You are using i believe `socialShare` variable for this. And most probably you are using a `ng-repeat` so this variable is being created on each repeat scope effectively creating n `socialShare` variable not accessible outside the repeat child scope.

One way you can fix this would be to make the `socialShare` variable available on the article object this line becomes

```
<div social-share ng-show="article.socialShare" class="social-share arrow-down">
```

and this becomes

`<a ng-click="toggle(article)" class="share-article clickable">`

In the controller create methods like

```
$scope.toggle=function(article) {
    angular.forEach(articles,function(article) { 
         article.socialShare=false;   //This would close all open items
    });
    article.socialShare=true;         // This will show the item selected.

}
```

You can also look at library [angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) accordion control.

Comment: Very cool! Now how would you add back the functionality for the actual toggle (ie: double clicking sets `article.socialShare` back to `false`)?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out and added it to your answer for future viewers. Thanks!